# How to delete in mongoDB - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a small-scale school project where I need to 'create an app' that manages a list of contacts.
I'm really new to Nodejs and mongodb and sadly I cannot find any answer in the internet.

I'm trying to delete a record from a document, by debugging I know that the data (id) is sent correctly to the server.

```
 router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    db.contacts.deleteOne
       ({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('deleted ' + res);
        res.status(200)
        .json({message: 'Deletion successful! '})
    });
});
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, I guess you're using mongojs, mongojs doesn't contain a deleteOne method, so you have to rely on the provided API for that purpose by using :

```
db.collection.remove(query, [justOne], [callback])
```

More details on mongoJs official documentation [Here](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs)

Comment: yeah, i was following along a video that didn't put too much info on the differences, well, a rookie's mistake i guess! thank you very much :)